# AWS S3 Web hosting, hidingsource files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

## How to make files innacessible on AWS S3

First i want to apologize if this is a duplicate of any question. I have not found any information regarding my question.

I want to have a website hosted on AWS S3. The website uses some libraries that i dont want people have access to. If I make a standard policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {"AWS": "*"},
    "Action": ["s3:GetObject"],
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::www.my-website.com/*"]
  }]
}
```

I will make the bucket public and everyone will be able to get to those files. If I make all but those source files public, the website won't work. I tried replacing the `"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::www.my-website.com/*"]` with `"NotResource": ["arn:aws:s3:::www.my-website.com/library/*"]`. It made those files private, but the website was not working again.
I currently dont have my own registered domain.

#### Question

So my question is, how to make a website run without making source files public. Is it even posible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another statement that restricts access to source files. Explicit deny supersedes any permission you grant.

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {"AWS": "*"},
       "Action": ["s3:GetObject"],
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::www.my-website.com/*"]
     },
     {
       "Sid": "Restrict source files",
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Principal": {"AWS": "*"},
       "Action": ["s3:GetObject"],
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::www.my-website.com/src/*"]
     }
  ]
}
```

I'm assuming your source files are in a `src` directory in the web root.

I use a different strategy for dealing with this: When I deploy static sites to s3, I deploy the compiled distributable files. The source files never make it to the bucket.

Comment: @Razmooo You cat access denied for everything? Just to clarify: the source files are not actually being used in production right? I'm assuming that you have distributable files that are compiled from the source files.

Comment: Current status is:
When i go to aws s3 page into my bucket, i get access denied for all files under `src`. But when i go to my electron application (webpage is actually loaded in electron), the webpage is working, but i get acces denied for two files. The biggest problem is that i can see all source code of all files in library in developer console under `sources` tab, even though thay are blocked on s3. Am i doing something wrong here. Its my first time trying to host a static webpage

Comment: @Razmooo Where are the two files that are restricted? Also, do you have sourcemaps? Unless you are actually using the source files in your application, the only time they should show up in your dev tools is if you have sourcemaps that reference the source files.

Comment: nevermind, i found that on all websites that use this library, I can see the source in sources in Dev tools. I will have to contact the company that owns the library.

Comment: @Razmooo just to confirm,  this method did work for restricting the files though,  correct?